# High training error at the beginning of training a Convolutional neural network

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, biological-neural-network

In the Convolutional neural network,
I'm working on training a CNN, and during the training process, especially at the beginning of my training I get extremely high training error. After that, this error starts to go down slowly. After approximately 500 Epochs the training error comes near to zero (e.g. 0.006604). Then, I took the final obtained model to measure its accuracy against the testing data, I've got about 89.50%.
Does that seem normal? I mean getting a high training error rate at the very beginning of my training process.
Another thing I'd like to mention is that I've noticed that every time I decrease the number of hidden nodes, the results become better at the end of my training.

My CNN structure is:

```
 config.forward_pass_scheme = {'conv_v', 'pool', 'conv_v', 'pool', 'conv_v', 'pool', 'conv_v','full', 'full', 'full', 'out'};
```

Here are some of my hyper parameters:

```
  config.learning_rate = 0.01;
  config.weight_range = 2;
  config.decay = 0.0005;
  config.normalize_init_weights = 1;
  config.dropout_full_layer = 1;
  config.optimization = 'adagrad';
```

Your help and suggestion in this regard is highly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large number of hidden units in fully connected (fc) layers and do not have sufficient training data, the network will overfit to the training set. Convolutional layers are less prone to overfitting as they have less parameters. Reducing the number of hidden units in the fc layers can reduce overfitting. To tune these hyper-parameters (like number of hidden nodes in a fc layer), a validation set is used, so that the model gives good performance on the test set. Although dropout helps in reducing overfitting in fc layers, it may not be sufficient if you add too many hidden units.

Yes, in the beginning, it is expected that training error would be high. CNNs are trained using stochastic optimization, so it takes some time to learn the parameters.

Comment: Dear Bharat, Thank you for your answer, 
In fact, what I'm doing is that after each Epoch ( complete pass through the training data), I evaluate the training error using a batch from the training set. Is that what do you mean by the validation set?. Another thing I already use the drop out with the Adagrad optimization method.

From your answer I understand that normal to get a high training error at the beginning.

Comment: Validation set is separate from the training set. Although looking at training error gives some idea weather the optimization is converging or not, it does not tell if the model is over fitting. Therefore a validation set (or a small portion of the training set which is not used for training) is used to measure the performance of the model. Yes, just after the first epoch training error could be high.

Comment: No, In my case, it differs. 
It starts high and then goes down very slowly. However, I get a good results on the testing set. Just, throwing a high training error at beginning is bothering me.

Answer (score 0):

The more hidden layers/neurons, the more weights in your NN. It means more parameters to model your problem. Therefore it makes sense that add neurons/layers gives better learning.

On the other way, more weights to train means more risks of overfitting. Be sure that you have at least 5 times more samples in your training set that you have weights in your NN.

An other solution to prevent overfitting is to use a dropout.

Btw, which library do you use?

Comment: Dear FiReTiTi, thank you for your help,
In the first two lines you're saying with more layers/neurons a better result will be obtained, but what is happening in my CNN,  as I reduce the number of the hidden neurons a better results are obtained. 

I use this code  [ here](https://github.com/jimmy-ren/vcnn_double-bladed   )

Comment: The weights initialization is random, so run twice the same architecture on the same data may provide different results. And I would have had been more specific when I said result into my answer, I meant learning. The more weights, the better the learning, but maybe the worse the prediction on the test set.

Comment: This is what I was thinking about it. Does generate the weights randomly in each time correct? and what is the best way to ensure the best result  or at less the same result for each implementation.

Comment: And can you please, explain to me what do you mean by this 
(Be sure that you have at least 5 times more samples in your training set that you have weights in your NN).

Comment: The only way to set the same weights is to specify the seed before generating the random values.

Comment: For your second question, I mean that the size of the training set (the number of instances, not the batch size) must be at least 5 times bigger than the number of weights in your NN.

Comment: Please, I,m new to the  deep learning and I need more explanation to get the idea. what do you mean by (The only way to set the same weights is to specify the seed before generating the random values). In my CNN the weights values are generated randomly between [0,2].

Comment: After I've made search on it, I understood what do you mean by specifying the seed before generating the random values. Should I put this seed  **rng(1);** at the beginning of  my script? or before each use of randn function?

Comment: One seed should be enough.