# How can I control the randomness of the generated weights?

Tags: random, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working on training Constitutional Neural Network, and each time I run my model I get different training error rate. Following my previous question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36021478/high-training-error-at-the-beginning-of-training-a-convolutional-neural-network)
I found that the main cause is the way in which the weights are generated(randomly) where each time I train my CNN it starts from different point. So, I'm looking for a way that can help me to control the randomness of my weights and  keep the same output each time.

One person in my previous question suggested to use the seed. In fact, I tried this code at the beginning of my code, but I'm not quite sure it works correctly.

Here is the function which responsible for initialize the weights randomly:

```
 function init(flag)
 % In this function, a number of the fields will be added to the Config
 % structure to complete the full configuration of our CNN model for both   Forward and Backward pipeline.
 % Notice that all the functions with names have a B captal letter at medil
 % are for Backword pipeline (e.g. convBpool, and convBconv).
% Inputs: 
s = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',1);
RandStream.setGlobalStream(s);
% flag: 0 for training, 1 for testing
global config;

config.GEN_OUTPUT = @gen_output_copy;
if strcmp(config.compute_device, 'GPU')
    init_gpu(1);% Enable the GPU device.
    config.NEW_MEM = @to_gpu; % it a handle function to send the data on GPU
    config.IM2COL = @im2col_gpu;% Perform the im2col function on the GPU
else
    config.NEW_MEM = @to_cpu;
    config.IM2COL = @im2col;
end
%  Perform th all the nonlinearity functions on the GPU
if strcmp(config.nonlinearity, 'relu')
    config.NONLINEARITY = @relu;
elseif strcmp(config.nonlinearity, 'tanh')
    config.NONLINEARITY = @tanh;
elseif strcmp(config.nonlinearity, 'sigmoid')
    config.NONLINEARITY = @sigmoid;
else
    config.NONLINEARITY = @tanh;
    fprintf('nonlinearity spec error, use tanh by default\n');
end

if strcmp(config.output_activation, 'softmax')
    config.OUT_ACT = @softmax;
elseif strcmp(config.output_activation, 'inherit')
    config.OUT_ACT = config.NONLINEARITY;
elseif strcmp(config.output_activation, 'nil')
    config.OUT_ACT = @nonlinearity_nil;
else
    config.OUT_ACT = @softmax;
    fprintf('output_activation spec error, use softmax by default\n');
end

if strcmp(config.cost_function, 'cross entropy')
    config.COST_FUN = @cross_entropy;
elseif strcmp(config.cost_function, 'L2 norm')
    config.COST_FUN = @L2_norm;
else
    config.COST_FUN = @cross_entropy;
    fprintf('cost_function spec error, use cross_entropy by default\n');
end

config.cost = 0;
config.misc.current_layer = 1;

% initialize weights and calculate some statistics
r = config.weight_range;    
conv_layer_c = 0;
pool_layer_c = 0;
full_layer_c = 0;

layer_num = length(config.forward_pass_scheme)-1;% length(config.forward_pass_scheme) is the number of the layers.
config.layer_num = layer_num;

config.feature_map_sizes = {};
config.weights = {};
for idx = 1:layer_num
    if idx == 1
        conv_layer_c = conv_layer_c + 1;
                                         % Determine the size of the features maps in the first layer along with the Depth of Volume.
        config.feature_map_sizes{idx} = [config.input_size(1)-config.kernel_size(1,1)+1 config.input_size(2)-config.kernel_size(1,2)+1 ...
                                         config.conv_hidden_size(conv_layer_c)];
        %config.misc.mask_type = 16;     % hard code here for now
        %config.misc.mask_type = 4;
        if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'conv_v_sr')
            config.weights{idx} = {};
            for t = 1:config.misc.mask_type
                config.weights{idx}{t} = config.NEW_MEM(randn(config.feature_map_sizes{idx}(3), ...
                                          config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 1)*config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 2)*config.chs)*r);
            end
            % create mask and generate conv index
            mask_mem();
            %mask = config.NEW_MEM([1 0;0 0]);
            mask = config.NEW_MEM([1 0 0 0;0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0]);
            mask = repmat(mask, config.input_size(1)/sqrt(config.misc.mask_type), config.input_size(2)/sqrt(config.misc.mask_type), config.chs);
            mask = repmat(mask, 1,1,1,config.batch_size);
            mask2conv(mask);
        elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'conv_v')
            config.weights{idx} = config.NEW_MEM(randn(config.feature_map_sizes{idx}(3), ...
                                          config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 1)*config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 2)*config.chs)*r);
            if config.normalize_init_weights
                config.weights{idx} = config.weights{idx} / sqrt(config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 1) * config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 2) * config.conv_hidden_size(conv_layer_c));
            end
        elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'conv_v_mask_norm')
            config.weights{idx} = config.NEW_MEM(randn(config.feature_map_sizes{idx}(3), ...
                                          config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 1)*config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 2)*config.chs)*r) + r;
            if config.normalize_init_weights
                config.weights{idx} = config.weights{idx} / sqrt(config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 1) * config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 2) * config.conv_hidden_size(conv_layer_c));
            end
        end
    elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'conv_v')
        conv_layer_c = conv_layer_c + 1;
        config.feature_map_sizes{idx} = [config.feature_map_sizes{idx-1}(1)-config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c,1)+1 ...
                                         config.feature_map_sizes{idx-1}(2)-config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c,2)+1 ...
                                         config.conv_hidden_size(conv_layer_c)];
        config.weights{idx} = config.NEW_MEM(randn(config.feature_map_sizes{idx}(3), ...
                                      config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 1)*config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 2)*config.feature_map_sizes{idx-1}(3))*r);
        if config.normalize_init_weights
            config.weights{idx} = config.weights{idx} / sqrt(config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 1) * config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 2) * config.conv_hidden_size(conv_layer_c));
        end
    elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'conv_f')
        conv_layer_c = conv_layer_c + 1;
        if idx == layer_num
            config.weights{idx} = config.NEW_MEM(randn(config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 1)*config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 2)*config.output_size(3), config.conv_hidden_size(conv_layer_c-1))*r);
            if config.normalize_init_weights
                config.weights{idx} = config.weights{idx} / sqrt(config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 1) * config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 2) * size(config.weights{idx}, 1));
            end
            config.GEN_OUTPUT = @gen_output_from_conv_f;
        else
            fprintf('in init(): conv_f layer in the hidden layer not supported yet.\n');
        end
    elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'pool')
        pool_layer_c = pool_layer_c + 1;  % Determine the zise of the feature maps in the pool layer. 
        config.feature_map_sizes{idx} = [config.feature_map_sizes{idx-1}(1)/2 config.feature_map_sizes{idx-1}(2)/2 ...
                                         config.feature_map_sizes{idx-1}(3)];            
        config.weights{idx} = config.NEW_MEM(randn(config.feature_map_sizes{idx-1}(3), 1) * r) / 4;            
    elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'full')
        full_layer_c = full_layer_c + 1;            
        if idx == layer_num
            config.weights{idx} = config.NEW_MEM(randn(config.output_size(3), config.feature_map_sizes{idx-1}(3)) * r);
            if config.normalize_init_weights
                config.weights{idx} = config.weights{idx} / sqrt(config.output_size(3));
            end
        else
            config.feature_map_sizes{idx} = [1 1 config.full_hidden_size(full_layer_c)];
            config.weights{idx} = config.NEW_MEM(randn(config.feature_map_sizes{idx}(3), ...
                config.feature_map_sizes{idx-1}(1)*config.feature_map_sizes{idx-1}(2)*config.feature_map_sizes{idx-1}(3)) * r);
            if config.normalize_init_weights
                config.weights{idx} = config.weights{idx} / sqrt(config.feature_map_sizes{idx}(3));
            end
        end            
    end
end

% initialize bias
for idx = 1:layer_num-1
    config.weights{idx+layer_num} = config.NEW_MEM(zeros(config.feature_map_sizes{idx}(3), 1)+0.01);
end
if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{layer_num}, 'conv_f')
    config.weights{layer_num*2} = config.NEW_MEM(zeros(size(config.weights{layer_num}, 1), 1)+0.05);
else
    config.weights{layer_num*2} = config.NEW_MEM(zeros(config.output_size(3), 1)+0.05);
end

% prepare memory
reset_mem();
input_mem();
if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{1}, 'conv_v_mask_norm')
    mask_mem();
end
if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{2}, 'conv_v')
    conv2conv_mem(1);
end
for m = 2:layer_num
    if strfind(config.forward_pass_scheme{m}, 'conv')
        conv_mem(m);
        if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{m+1}, 'out')
            conv2out_mem();
        elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{m+1}, 'conv_v')
            conv2conv_mem(m);
        end
    elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{m}, 'pool')
        pool_mem(m);
        if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{m+1}, 'conv_v')
            pool2conv_mem(m);
        end
    elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{m}, 'full')
        full_mem(m);
    end
end

% building forward pipeline
config.pipeline_forward = {};
config.pipeline_forward{1} = @input2conv;
if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{1}, 'conv_v_mask_norm')
    config.pipeline_forward{2} = @mask2conv;
end
conv_layer_c = 1;
for idx = 1:layer_num
    if strfind(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'conv')
        conv_layer_c = conv_layer_c + 1;
        if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'conv_v_sr')
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @conv_forward_SR;
        else
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @conv_forward;
        end
        if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'conv_v_mask_norm')
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @mask_conv_forward;
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @mask_normalize;
        end
        if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx+1}, 'conv_v')
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @nonlinearity;
            if config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 1) == 1 && config.kernel_size(conv_layer_c, 2) == 1
                config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @conv2conv1by1;
            else
                config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @conv2conv;
            end
        elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx+1}, 'conv_f')
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @nonlinearity;
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @conv2conv_f;
        elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx+1}, 'pool')
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @nonlinearity;
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @conv2pool;
        elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx+1}, 'full')
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @nonlinearity;
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @conv2full;
        elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx+1}, 'out')
            if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'conv_f')
                config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @conv2out;
                config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @out_forward;
            else
                fprintf('in init(): currently only support conv_f as the output conv layer.\n');
            end
        end
    elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'pool')
        config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @pool_forward;
        config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @nonlinearity;
        if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx+1}, 'conv_v')
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @pool2conv;
        elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx+1}, 'pool')
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @pool2pool;
        elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx+1}, 'full')
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @pool2full;
        end
    elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'full')
        config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @full_forward;
        if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx+1}, 'full')
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @nonlinearity;
            if config.dropout_full_layer == 1
                config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @dropout_forward;
            end
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @full2full;
        elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx+1}, 'out')
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @full2out;
            config.pipeline_forward{length(config.pipeline_forward)+1} = @out_forward;
        end
    end
end

config.SCALE_INPUT = @scale_input_nil;
config.SCALE_OUTPUT = @scale_output_nil;

if flag ~= 0
    return;
end
config.EXPAND_DELTA_OUT = @expand_delta_out_nil;
if strcmp(config.nonlinearity, 'relu')
    config.DERI_NONLINEARITY = @deri_relu;
elseif strcmp(config.nonlinearity, 'tanh')
    config.DERI_NONLINEARITY = @deri_tanh;
elseif strcmp(config.nonlinearity, 'sigmoid')
    config.DERI_NONLINEARITY = @deri_sigmoid;
else
    config.DERI_NONLINEARITY = @deri_tanh;        
end

if strcmp(config.output_activation, 'softmax')
    config.DERI_OUT_ACT = @deri_softmax;
elseif strcmp(config.output_activation, 'inherit')
    config.DERI_OUT_ACT = @deri_inherit;
elseif strcmp(config.output_activation, 'nil')
    config.DERI_OUT_ACT = @deri_nonlinearity_nil;
else
    config.DERI_OUT_ACT = @deri_softmax;        
end

if strcmp(config.cost_function, 'cross entropy')
    config.DERI_COST_FUN = @deri_cross_entropy;
elseif strcmp(config.cost_function, 'L2 norm')
    config.DERI_COST_FUN = @deri_L2_norm;
else
    config.DERI_COST_FUN = @deri_cross_entropy;        
end

for m = 2:layer_num        
    if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{m}, 'conv_v')            
        if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{m-1}, 'pool')
            convBpool_mem(m);
        elseif strfind(config.forward_pass_scheme{m}, 'conv')
            conv_layer_id = get_conv_layer_idx_from_layer_idx(m);
            if config.kernel_size(conv_layer_id, 1) ~= 1 && config.kernel_size(conv_layer_id, 2) ~= 1
                convBconv_mem(m);
            end
        end        
    end
end

% building pipeline for backprop
config.pipeline_backprop = {};
config.pipeline_backprop{1} = @out_backprop;
for idx = layer_num+1:-1:3
    if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'out')
        if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx-1}, 'conv_f')
            config.EXPAND_DELTA_OUT = @expand_delta_out_for_conv_f;
            config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @outBconv;
            config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @conv_backprop;
        elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx-1}, 'full')
            config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @outBfull;
            config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @full_backprop;
        else
            fprintf('in init(): backprop from the output layer to the specified layer is not yet supported.\n');
        end            
    elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'conv_f')
        if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx-1}, 'conv_v')                
            config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @convBconv_1by1;                
        else
            fprintf('in init(): backprop from conv_f to the specified layer is not yet supported.\n');
        end
        config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @conv_backprop;
    elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'conv_v')
        if strfind(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx-1}, 'conv')
            conv_layer_id = get_conv_layer_idx_from_layer_idx(idx);
            if config.kernel_size(conv_layer_id, 1) == 1 && config.kernel_size(conv_layer_id, 2) == 1
                config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @convBconv_1by1;
            else
                config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @convBconv;
            end
            config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @conv_backprop;
        elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx-1}, 'pool')
            config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @convBpool;
            config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @pool_backprop;
        end            
    elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'pool')
        if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx-1}, 'conv_v')
            config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @poolBconv;
            config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @conv_backprop;
        elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx-1}, 'pool')
            config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @poolBpool;
            config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @pool_backprop;
        end            
    elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx}, 'full')
        if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx-1}, 'full')
            config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @fullBfull;
        elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx-1}, 'conv_v')
            config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @fullBconv;
        elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{idx-1}, 'pool')
            config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @fullBpool;
        end
        config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @full_backprop;
    end                
end
if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{2}, 'conv_v') && config.kernel_size(2, 1) ~= 1 && config.kernel_size(2, 2) ~= 1
    config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @convBconv_last;
end
if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{1}, 'conv_v_mask_norm')
    if strcmp(config.mask_for_SR, 'true')
        config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @convBinput_with_mask_accel;
    else
        config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @convBinput_with_mask;
    end
elseif strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{1}, 'conv_v_sr')
    config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @convBinput_SR;
else
    config.pipeline_backprop{length(config.pipeline_backprop)+1} = @convBinput;
end    

if strcmp(config.optimization, 'adagrad')        
    config.his_grad = {};
    config.fudge_factor = 1e-6;
    if strcmp(config.forward_pass_scheme{1}, 'conv_v_sr')
        config.UPDATE_WEIGHTS = @update_weights_adagrad_SR;
        config.his_grad{1} = {};
        for m = 1:config.misc.mask_type
            config.his_grad{1}{m} = config.NEW_MEM(zeros(size(config.weights{1}{m})));
        end
        for m = 2:length(config.weights)
            config.his_grad{m} = config.NEW_MEM(zeros(size(config.weights{m})));
        end
    else
        config.UPDATE_WEIGHTS = @update_weights_adagrad;
        for m = 1:length(config.weights)
            config.his_grad{m} = config.NEW_MEM(zeros(size(config.weights{m})));% Attach all the weights vectors on the GPU.
        end
    end
else
    fprintf('optimization method not supported, use adagrad as default\n');
    config.UPDATE_WEIGHTS = @update_weights_adagrad;
 end
end
```

I'll be grateful, if you could help me to sort this issue out.

Comment: Please post the MCVE that illustrates your uncertainty.

Comment: what do you mean by MCVE?!

Comment: if you do not post any code - you will not get any code related answer.

Comment: [MCVE is described in the help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This was part of the intro tour you were offered upon setting up your account.  MCVE is the abbreviation we use.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I found that putting

```
s = RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',1);
RandStream.setGlobalStream(s);
```

at top of my function can control the randomness in generating the weights in my CNN. To test it's work, I'v implemented the same model 5 times and each time approximately the same results is obtained. 
Thank you for all of you.

Answer (score 0):

I just happen to be having the same non-deterministic results problem of my tensorflow code.   I also tried setting the seed for random generators but does not help.
Later I found this discussion :(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2732)   . It states that the cause is likely due to the modern GPU framework, so it seems like there's no good fix until CUDA updates it.